# Problem srapping Harvey Norman with Beautifulsoup-Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The "name" list is longer than the "price" list. This is due to some items in Harvy Norman does not have a price [Inspect element at Harvey Norman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crKWq.png). How can I ignor items that does not have a price? For example, not appending the item name in the list "name".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

name = []
price = []


for i in range(1, 100):

    url = 'https://www.harveynorman.com.au/catalogsearch/result/index/?p='  + str(i) + '&q=game'
    print(url)


    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    ii = 0

    for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'name fn l_mgn-tb-sm l_dsp-blc'}):

        ii = ii + 1
        name.append(item.get_text(strip=True))

    for item in soup.findAll(["div"], {'class': ['product-item']}, limit = ii):
        aia = item.get_text(strip=True)
        #aia = aia[1:]
        price.append(aia)

    driver.close()
```

Comment: You probably should ignore the entire Hardly Normal website altogether, they're hideously expensive :-) But here's an upvote for a relatively well-researched question, wish I could help you out.

Comment: so all your target is getting item with price or without price ?

Comment: αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη with price please. Glad to see you around!

Comment: :D working on it.

Comment: Actually Harvy Norman is a bit cheaper than JB HI-Fi at the camera paxdiablo.

Comment: @EdwardLiu you want item name and price ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import csv

output = []
for page in range(1, 11):
    print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.harveynorman.com.au/catalogsearch/tracking/search?p={page}&q=game&format=json").json()
    for item in r['results']:
        if item['price'] != "":
            result = item['title'], item['price']
            output.append(result)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Price'])
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: @EdwardLiu http://www.sharecsv.com/s/09b69e4145379dd1afab50728ac5efc7/result.csv this is the first 10 pages.

Comment: @EdwardLiu Ops, hold on i found that the parameters is auto generated per session. let me have a workaround about this.

Comment: DW. I think I found a hack to it! Will post it in a sec

Comment: the issue here is incapsula firewall.